# python2.7 - reading a dictionary from a .txt file riddled with unicode

Tags: python, unicode, dictionary

I enrolled into a Chinese Studies course some time ago, and I thought it'd be a great exercise for me to write a flashcard program in python. I'm storing the flash card lists in a dictionary in a .txt file, so far without trouble. The real problems kick in when I try to load the file, encoded in utf-8, into my program. An excerpt of my code:

```
import codecs

f = codecs.open(('list.txt'),'r','utf-8')
quiz_list = eval(f.read())

quizy = str(quiz_list).encode('utf-8')

print quizy
```

Now, if for example list.txt consists of:

```
{'character1':'男人'}
```

what is printed is actually

```
{'character1': '\xe7\x94\xb7\xe7\x86\xb1'}
```

Obviously there are some serious encoding issues here, but I cannot for the life of me understand *where* these occur. I am working with a terminal which supports utf-8, so not the standard cmd.exe: this is not the problem. Reading a normal list.txt without the curly dict-bits returns the chinese characters without a problem, so my guess is I'm not handling the dictionary part correctly. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your encoding... Look at this:

```
>>> d = {1:'男人'}
>>> d[1]
'\xe7\x94\xb7\xe4\xba\xba'
>>> print d[1]
男人
```

One thing is to print a unicode string another one is printing its representation.

Comment: also @ephemient Thanks both! I figured it out, apparently I should've done my research a little better. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2):

`str(quizy)` calls `repr(quizy['character1'])` which produces an ASCII representation of the string value.  If you just `print quizy['character1']` you'll see that the character codes are Unicode in the Python string.